# JavaScript string to integer

Tags: javascript, string, integer, var, parseint

I'm making a conversion app and I keep getting return Not a Number (NaN)

```
function conversion() {
                var bill = document.getElementById('bill');
                var mates = document.getElementById('mates');
                console.log(bill);
                console.log(mates);
                var pay = parseInt(bill)/parseInt(mates);
                alert("Each mate pays: " + pay);
            }
```

Can't figure out why it won't return in integer.

Comment: I assume the elements are `input`s?

Comment: check the values logged in the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse an HTML Element into an integer. What you probably want is to get the values from the inputs:

```
var bill = document.getElementById('bill').value;
var mates = document.getElementById('mates').value;
```

Comment: if they are not inputs use innerText instead of value.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the values, now you are parsing entire elements.

```
function conversion() {
            var bill = document.getElementById('bill').value; // <---
            var mates = document.getElementById('mates').value; // <---
            console.log(bill);
            console.log(mates);
            var pay = parseInt(bill)/parseInt(mates);
            alert("Each mate pays: " + pay);
        }
```